# Customized CSS codes not loading in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I add a style sheet file to my project for customized style sheets. this file is in this path: ~/Content/MyStyle.css

When I run my project this file exists in the browser but there isn't any code in it.

Even I append my codes to Site.css file, those codes are wrote by mvc as default are exist, but those codes I added is not exist.

I'm confused. I wrote some code but not appear in browser.
Can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a caching issue. You have to hard-refresh your browser. Try pressing `ctrl`+`shift`+`R` or `ctrl`+`F5`.

This will make sure that your modified files are requested from the server.

You can also change caching settings for your local development environment. Refer to MSDN on how to make a `web.debug.config` config transformation and what settings to change.